# Optimización de Apache para alto tráfico con MPM Event

Tags: servidor, apache2, optimización

Actualmente administro el siguiente conjunto de servidores que sirven alrededor de 700 páginas web:

### SERVIDOR 1 (WEB)

- Servidor web: Apache 2.4.29 con MPM Event
- PHP 7.2.22
- Intel Xeon CPU E5-2673 v4 @2.30GHz (4 cores) 16 GB memoria
- S.O: Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS
- Premium SSD 250GB

### SERVIDOR 2 (Base de Datos)

- DB: mysql 10.2.26
- Intel Xeon CPU E5-2673 v4 @2.30GHz (8 cores) 32 GB memoria
- S.O: Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

Ambos servidores están conectados en la misma red local.

Recurrentemente tengo problemas de rendimiento y creo que es por no tener Apache optimizado correctamente.

El servidor web recibe muchas peticiones web que no gestiona bien y produce alto consumo de CPU y en consecuencia lentitud en todo el servidor.

Actualmente esta es la configuración MPM con la que trabajo y creo que no gestiona las conexiones correctamente.

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers            2
        MinSpareThreads         25
        MaxSpareThreads         75
        ThreadLimit             64
        ThreadsPerChild         25
        MaxRequestWorkers       550
        ServerLimit             32
        MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme una configuración óptima del MPM según los requisitos y características del servidor?

Comment: @JackNavaRow a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: creo que debes hacer la configuracion de peticiones a cada virtualhost de tu servidor apache2

Answer (score 0):

Mira lo que puedo decirte desde mi experiencia es que debes subir el ServerLimit para que sea igual que MaxRequestWorkers, ademas debes subir tambien este valor, esto acorde a lo que tu memoria pueda soportar.

Startservers es muy poco 2, tienes 4 cores, lo aconsejable seria por lo menos 4
MaxConnectionsPerChild  0   esta bien, pero tambien podrias poner un numero grande, por ej 1000  o 2000